# What could be the short pulse in this I2C time diagram?

Tags: i2c

I'm using a microcontroller which is receiving data from a sensor through I2C protocol. And I wanted use a USB logic analyzer to see clock and data lines of I2C.

Code works fine but as you see [here](https://ibb.co/s1G3bCP) in red there is a very short pulse which is not part of data logic. And its randomly appears at the same location. What could be the reason for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the point where one device stops pulling the data wire low after the last data bit of a byte, so the other device can start pulling the data wire low for the acknowledge bit.

During the period where no device pulls the data wire low, it is high.

Just count the clock pulses. It's likely always between 8th and 9th clock pulse, when the data wire at 8th clock pulse is low and for ACK it needs to be low for the 9th pulse too.